# What is a proper way to modify and upload multiple large images using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

Here's what I have to do:

1. Load max. 1000 pictures to the browser's memory
2. Modify each photo
3. Send all photos to the server (Firebase)

I have no problems with points 2 and 3.
The problem is with point 1.

I am looking for a good way to temporarily store files in the browser memory. I tried two ways:

- A. App state
- B. IndexedDB

There are pros and cons to these two solutions.

Point A - access to data is fast but large amounts of data sometimes cause the browser crash.

Point B - the data is secure but loading into IndexedDB takes a long time and takes up additional space on the device.

Maybe you know better ways to store files temporarily and permanently in browser's memory?